# customizable letter replacer

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I've been working on an app that pretty much replaces letters.
So you'll have a letter and an input box. The letter reprecents what letter will be replaced, and you write what you want it to be replaced with in the input box. For this I used regex and objects.

If you wander like *@anonymous*, what exactly is wrong:

> @julianavar What doesn't work about it? What is the specific problem that you are having? –  Anonymous

Here is the answer:

> @Anonymous #extra-customizing doesn't work. Let's just say that you decide to replace in #extra-customizing the following: a with b, b with c, c with d. Don't change anything else. Now type "abcd" click translate, and you'll see that #extra-customizing doesn't overwrite #customizing –  julian avar

The problem is, **What if you want to replace whatever the user chooses with whatever the user chooses**?

The code below includes coment to simplify, and is also overall simplified. I added the CSS in order to create some sort of order.

To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, here is the link http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/debug/BywZYL.

Or you can always view it here:

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");
var extra_customizing = $("#extra-customizing");

String.prototype.cap = function() { // needed or demonstration
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

function translate() {
  var input = $("#input");
  var value = input.val();

  // Retriving #customizing
  /*
    I retrieve the values of the input boxes, in order to replace them later
  */
  // needed or demonstration
  var IDa = $("#a").val();
  var IDb = $("#b").val();
  var IDc = $("#c").val();
  var IDd = $("#d").val();

  // Retriving #extra-customizing
  /*
    Using the same logic as the other ones
  */
  var ID_ax = $("#Ax").val(); // input
  var ID_ay = $("#Ay").val(); // output
  var ID_bx = $("#Bx").val(); // input
  var ID_by = $("#By").val(); // output
  var ID_cx = $("#Cx").val(); // input
  var ID_cy = $("#Cy").val(); // output
  /*
    If the user inputs something to replace, they MUST have something to to replace it with(may change later)
  */
  if(ID_ax != "" && ID_ax == "") {
    alert("You have not insterted a value in #1");
  }
  if(ID_bx != "" && ID_bx == "") {
    alert("You have not insterted a value in #2");
  }
  if(ID_cx != "" && ID_cx == "") {
    alert("You have not insterted a value in #3");
  }

  // Setting
  var mapObj = {
    // Setting #customizing
    /*
      I first select what the user would write, and the what it should be replaced with
    */
    a: IDa,
    b: IDb,
    c: IDc,
    d: IDd,
    A: IDa.cap(),
    B: IDb.cap(),
    C: IDc.cap(),
    D: IDd.cap(),

    // Setting #extra-customizing
    /*
      I'm trying to use the same logic, but it is unsuccesful
    */
    ID_ay: ID_ax,
    ID_by: ID_bx,
    ID_cy: ID_cx
  }; 

  // Translating
  /*
    Below is the code used to replace letters
  */
  var re = new
  RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"g");
  value = value.replace(re, function(matched) {
    return mapObj[matched];
  });
  
  output.val(value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}

hr {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(50em + 195px);
  width: -moz-calc(50em + 195px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#extra-customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(55em + 282px);
  width: -moz-calc(55em + 282px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#customizing input, #extra-customizing input {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: "courier";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  padding-top: .2em;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#extra-customizing input {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#translator {
  width: 100%;
}


#extra-customize {
  width: 320px;
  margin: .2em auto 1em auto;
}

#extra-customize input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: .9em;
}

#input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 8.28%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}

#output {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customizing">
  a<input type="text" id="a" value="a" maxlenght="3">
  b<input type="text" id="b" value="b" maxlenght="3">
  c<input type="text" id="c" value="c" maxlenght="3">
  d<input type="text" id="d" value="d" maxlenght="3">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="extra-customizing">
  1<input type="text" id="Ax" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Ay" value="" maxlength="7">
  2<input type="text" id="Bx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="By" value="" maxlength="7">
  3<input type="text" id="Cx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Cy" value="" maxlength="7">
</div>

<div id="translator">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="translate()">
  <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're asking "What if the user wants to replace 'D' with 'D'?"? You have three options, all of which are very simple: 1) Run your code as usual and let it replace everything with itself. 2) Detect if the two are the same, and if so don't do anything but pretend you did. 3) Tell the user that you won't let them do that, and make them pick something else.

Comment: @krillgar thank you for that, it is quite useful, I didn't think about that. And now that I think about it, it should be 1)Run your code as usual and let it replace everything with itself., but still alert the user about it. Anyways, I'll worry about it later. Right now it doesn't work, so please help the cause. Thanks!

Comment: @julianavar What doesn't work about it? What is the specific problem that you are having?

Comment: @Anonymous `#extra-customizing` doesn't work. Let's just say that you decide to replace in `#extra-customizing` the following: a with b, b with c, c with d. Don't change anything else. Now type "abcd" click translate, and you'll see that `#extra-customizing` **doesn't** overwrite `#customizing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare your customizing properties, you're passing them a property name, thinking they'll be the same value as the variables that are named the same way. This can't be done inside of object declarations, since the property names will be taken as strings. You have to set them outside of the object, with square bracket notation.

However, [**in ECMAScript 6**, you're/will be able to set them inside of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), like this:

```
var prop = "foo";
var o = {
  [prop]: "hey",
  ["b" + "ar"]: "there"
};
```

*Currently supported only by Firefox and Safari*

Also, the function name of `translate` seems to throw an error in Chrome, not sure why, perhaps it is reserved for something else? I changed its name to `trans`.

**Take a look:**

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Lackjc/1/

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");
var extra_customizing = $("#extra-customizing");

String.prototype.cap = function () { // needed or demonstration
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

function trans() {
    var input = $("#input");
    var value = input.val();

    // Retriving #customizing
    /*
      I retrieve the values of the input boxes, in order to replace them later
    */
    // needed or demonstration
    var IDa = $("#a").val();
    var IDb = $("#b").val();
    var IDc = $("#c").val();
    var IDd = $("#d").val();

    // Retriving #extra-customizing
    /*
      Using the same logic as the other ones
    */
    var ID_ax = $("#Ax").val(); // input
    var ID_ay = $("#Ay").val(); // output
    var ID_bx = $("#Bx").val(); // input
    var ID_by = $("#By").val(); // output
    var ID_cx = $("#Cx").val(); // input
    var ID_cy = $("#Cy").val(); // output
    /*
      If the user inputs something to replace, they MUST have something to to replace it with(may change later)
    */
    if (ID_ax != "" && ID_ax == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #1");
    }
    if (ID_bx != "" && ID_bx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #2");
    }
    if (ID_cx != "" && ID_cx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #3");
    }

    // Setting
    var mapObj = {
        // Setting #customizing
        /*
          I first select what the user would write, and the what it should be replaced with
        */
        a: IDa,
        b: IDb,
        c: IDc,
        d: IDd,
        A: IDa.cap(),
        B: IDb.cap(),
        C: IDc.cap(),
        D: IDd.cap()
    };
    
    // Extra customizing
    mapObj[ID_ax] = ID_ay;
    mapObj[ID_bx] = ID_by;
    mapObj[ID_cx] = ID_cy;
    
    // Translating
    /*
      Below is the code used to replace letters
    */
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "g");
    console.log(re);
    value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
    output.val(value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}

hr {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(50em + 195px);
  width: -moz-calc(50em + 195px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#extra-customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(55em + 282px);
  width: -moz-calc(55em + 282px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#customizing input, #extra-customizing input {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: "courier";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  padding-top: .2em;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#extra-customizing input {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#translator {
  width: 100%;
}


#extra-customize {
  width: 320px;
  margin: .2em auto 1em auto;
}

#extra-customize input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: .9em;
}

#input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 8.28%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}

#output {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customizing">
  a<input type="text" id="a" value="a" maxlenght="3">
  b<input type="text" id="b" value="b" maxlenght="3">
  c<input type="text" id="c" value="c" maxlenght="3">
  d<input type="text" id="d" value="d" maxlenght="3">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="extra-customizing">
  1<input type="text" id="Ax" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Ay" value="" maxlength="7">
  2<input type="text" id="Bx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="By" value="" maxlength="7">
  3<input type="text" id="Cx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Cy" value="" maxlength="7">
</div>

<div id="translator">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="trans()">
  <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```