# letter replacer one character trouble

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a continuation to the following question: [customizable letter replacer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293795/customizable-letter-replacer)

I have a code that will replace letters, you can type whatever you want for a certain letter. For example, if you want to replace "l"s for "u"s, you type "hello" and the output would be "heuuo".

The problem comes when I want the user to be able to select any string to be replaced with any string. For example, if the user wants that "chicken" would be replaced by "nuggets".

The problem is, I can only select strings containing one letter. I cannot do as in the example above(chicken nuggets), but I can replace any one character by any amount of characters I want.

Please try to explain what is happening and not only give me the code, thanks!

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");
var extra_customizing = $("#extra-customizing");

String.prototype.cap = function () { // needed or demonstration
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

function trans() {
    var input = $("#input");
    var value = input.val();

    // Retriving #customizing
    /*
      I retrieve the values of the input boxes, in order to replace them later
    */
    // needed or demonstration
    var IDa = $("#a").val();
    var IDb = $("#b").val();
    var IDc = $("#c").val();
    var IDd = $("#d").val();

    // Retriving #extra-customizing
    /*
      Using the same logic as the other ones
    */
    var ID_ax = $("#Ax").val(); // input
    var ID_ay = $("#Ay").val(); // output
    var ID_bx = $("#Bx").val(); // input
    var ID_by = $("#By").val(); // output
    var ID_cx = $("#Cx").val(); // input
    var ID_cy = $("#Cy").val(); // output
    /*
      If the user inputs something to replace, they MUST have something to to replace it with(may change later)
    */
    if (ID_ax != "" && ID_ax == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #1");
    }
    if (ID_bx != "" && ID_bx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #2");
    }
    if (ID_cx != "" && ID_cx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #3");
    }

    // Setting
    var mapObj = {
        // Setting #customizing
        /*
          I first select what the user would write, and the what it should be replaced with
        */
        a: IDa,
        b: IDb,
        c: IDc,
        d: IDd,
        A: IDa.cap(),
        B: IDb.cap(),
        C: IDc.cap(),
        D: IDd.cap()
    };
    
    // Extra customizing
    mapObj[ID_ax] = ID_ay;
    mapObj[ID_bx] = ID_by;
    mapObj[ID_cx] = ID_cy;
    
    // Translating
    /*
      Below is the code used to replace letters
    */
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "g");
    console.log(re);
    value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
    output.val(value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}

hr {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(50em + 195px);
  width: -moz-calc(50em + 195px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#extra-customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(55em + 282px);
  width: -moz-calc(55em + 282px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#customizing input, #extra-customizing input {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: "courier";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  padding-top: .2em;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#extra-customizing input {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#translator {
  width: 100%;
}


#extra-customize {
  width: 320px;
  margin: .2em auto 1em auto;
}

#extra-customize input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: .9em;
}

#input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 8.28%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}

#output {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customizing">
  a<input type="text" id="a" value="a" maxlenght="3">
  b<input type="text" id="b" value="b" maxlenght="3">
  c<input type="text" id="c" value="c" maxlenght="3">
  d<input type="text" id="d" value="d" maxlenght="3">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="extra-customizing">
  1<input type="text" id="Ax" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Ay" value="" maxlength="7">
  2<input type="text" id="Bx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="By" value="" maxlength="7">
  3<input type="text" id="Cx" value="" maxlength="5">:<input type="text" id="Cy" value="" maxlength="7">
</div>

<div id="translator">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="trans()">
  <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter "chicken" and "nuggets" in the boxes to the right of "1," you get this regular expression:

```
/a|b|c|d|A|B|C|D|chicken|/g
```

Therefore, it will try to match anything containing an *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *A*, *B*, *C*, *D*, or *chicken*.

Since *c* comes before *chicken* in the regular expression's list, and *chicken* begins with a *c*, the word *chicken* will never bet matched.

What you should do is place the words before the letters in the regular expression.  You can do that like this:

```
var re = new RegExp(
  Object.keys(mapObj)
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.length - a.length;
    })
    .join("|"),
  "g"
);
```

The `sort` function changes the order of the keys so that the longest words come first.

The regular expression will then become:

```
/chicken|a|b|c|d|A|B|C|D|/g
```

**Snippet**

```js
// My globals
var output = $("#output");
var extra_customizing = $("#extra-customizing");

String.prototype.cap = function () { // needed or demonstration
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

function trans() {
    var input = $("#input");
    var value = input.val();

    // Retriving #customizing
    /*
      I retrieve the values of the input boxes, in order to replace them later
    */
    // needed or demonstration
    var IDa = $("#a").val();
    var IDb = $("#b").val();
    var IDc = $("#c").val();
    var IDd = $("#d").val();

    // Retriving #extra-customizing
    /*
      Using the same logic as the other ones
    */
    var ID_ax = $("#Ax").val(); // input
    var ID_ay = $("#Ay").val(); // output
    var ID_bx = $("#Bx").val(); // input
    var ID_by = $("#By").val(); // output
    var ID_cx = $("#Cx").val(); // input
    var ID_cy = $("#Cy").val(); // output
    /*
      If the user inputs something to replace, they MUST have something to to replace it with(may change later)
    */
    if (ID_ax != "" && ID_ax == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #1");
    }
    if (ID_bx != "" && ID_bx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #2");
    }
    if (ID_cx != "" && ID_cx == "") {
        alert("You have not insterted a value in #3");
    }

    // Setting
    var mapObj = {
        // Setting #customizing
        /*
          I first select what the user would write, and the what it should be replaced with
        */
        a: IDa,
        b: IDb,
        c: IDc,
        d: IDd,
        A: IDa.cap(),
        B: IDb.cap(),
        C: IDc.cap(),
        D: IDd.cap()
    };
    
    // Extra customizing
    mapObj[ID_ax] = ID_ay;
    mapObj[ID_bx] = ID_by;
    mapObj[ID_cx] = ID_cy;
    
    // Translating
    /*
      Below is the code used to replace letters
    */
    var re = new RegExp(
      Object.keys(mapObj)
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.length - a.length;
        })
        .join("|"),
      "g"
    );
    console.log(re);
    value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
    output.val(value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}

hr {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(50em + 195px);
  width: -moz-calc(50em + 195px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#extra-customizing {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: calc(55em + 282px);
  width: -moz-calc(55em + 282px);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#customizing input, #extra-customizing input {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: "courier";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
  padding-top: .2em;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#extra-customizing input {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#translator {
  width: 100%;
}


#extra-customize {
  width: 320px;
  margin: .2em auto 1em auto;
}

#extra-customize input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: .9em;
}

#input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 8.28%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}

#output {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customizing">
  a<input type="text" id="a" value="a" maxlenght="3">
  b<input type="text" id="b" value="b" maxlenght="3">
  c<input type="text" id="c" value="c" maxlenght="3">
  d<input type="text" id="d" value="d" maxlenght="3">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="extra-customizing">
  1<input type="text" id="Ax" value="" maxlength="7">:<input type="text" id="Ay" value="" maxlength="7">
  2<input type="text" id="Bx" value="" maxlength="7">:<input type="text" id="By" value="" maxlength="7">
  3<input type="text" id="Cx" value="" maxlength="7">:<input type="text" id="Cy" value="" maxlength="7">
</div>

<div id="translator">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="trans()">
  <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```