# string replacer and json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working in an app that will essentially replace strings with other strings inside a string.

example:
"nuggets" replaces "chicken"
`input = "I would like some chicken";`
`output = "I would like some nuggets";`

For this I will have a `textarea` as an input. The user will input a JSON object for this.

example:
`replacing_box_input = "{"a":"b","b":"c","c":"d","chicken":"nuggets"}";`
`input = "I would like some chicken abc";`
`output = "I would like some nuggets bcd";`

Here is the code I am using:

```js
var output = $("#output");

String.prototype.cap = function () {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

function trans() {
  var dic_editor = $("#dic-editor");
  var value = dic_editor.val();
  var mapObj = JSON.parse(value);

  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  }).join("|"), "g");

  value = value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return mapObj[matched];
  });

  output.val(value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "courier";
}

#explanation {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 1em;
  text-indent: 3em;
}

code {
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#dic-editor {
  width: calc(100% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - .86%);
  height: calc(100vh - 1.86em);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 1.86em);
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#input {
  width: calc(43% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(43% - .86%);
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 14%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}

#output {
  width: calc(43% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(43% - .86%);
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>Conlango</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Conlang: A Generator</h1>
    
    <textarea id="dic-editor"></textarea>
    
    <div id="translator">
      <textarea id="input"></textarea>
      <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="trans()">
      <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

The code is not replacing what it should. I need help figuring that out. Do any of you know why exactly is it not replacing the strings as it should?

Comment: I don't see an actual question here?

Comment: This is complicated -- how do you know `chicken` should turn into `nugget` and not have some of the letters replaced like the `c` going to `d`? Is the rules that the biggest match wins? Also, you have to be careful not replace `a` to `b` and then replace that same `b` to `c`.

Comment: I don't see a question either. ?

Comment: @ChrisTavares Sorry about that. I updated it for you.

Comment: @DavidElson Sorry about that. I updated it for you

Comment: @Cymen I have actually used this code before. The only "new" thing is JSON. If you want to what I mean by that take a look at this two articles: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810155/letter-replacer-one-character-trouble> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293795/customizable-letter-replacer>

Comment: @julianavar Still doesn't answer how `chicken` -> `nuggets` wins over `chicken` -> `dhicken` (due to `c` -> `d`).

Comment: @julianavar You still haven't really explained what the issue is. Effectively you say "it doesn't work." Could you please tell us 1) what you expect it to do, and 2)what it's actually doing? Also, cutting down the code to the bare minimum would really help, there's just too much noise in here right now.

Comment: @ChrisTavares I expect it to replace the key with the value but in a string. This is the bare minimum, The only thing that doesn't need to be there is the css, but you don't care about the css because you are working with js.

Comment: @Cymen If you read the questions above, you would of noticed that `var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).sort(function(a, b) {return b.length - a.length;  }).join("|"), "g");` should order the priorities. What ever pair of keys and values is first in the object is the prioritie, as you may or may have not noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example without being hooked up to the user interface:

```
String.prototype.cap = function () {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

function trans(value, jsonMap) {
  var mapObj = JSON.parse(jsonMap);

  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  }).join("|"), "g");

  return value.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return mapObj[matched];
  });
}

console.log(trans('I would like some chicken abc', '{"a":"b","b":"c","c":"d","chicken":"nuggets"}'));
```

The output when run is:

`I would like some nuggets bcd`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q80k9z2w/

And here it is hooked up to your UI: http://jsfiddle.net/d1rsof1q/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.map()` , `.val(function(index, value))`

```js
var output = $("#output");

var replacing_box_input = {
  "a": "b",
  "b": "c",
  "c": "d",
  "chicken": "nuggets"
};

function trans() {
  var dic_editor = $("#dic-editor");
  var fn = function(re, j) {
    return dic_editor.val().split(re).map(function(val, index) {
      return val in replacing_box_input ? replacing_box_input[val] : val
    }).join(j)
  };
  output.val(fn(/\s/, " ")).val(fn("", ""));
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #444444;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "courier";
}
#explanation {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 1em;
  text-indent: 3em;
}
code {
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#dic-editor {
  width: calc(100% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - .86%);
  height: calc(100vh - 1.86em);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 1.86em);
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
#input {
  width: calc(43% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(43% - .86%);
  height: 40vh;
  float: left;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inputB {
  font-family: "courier";
  width: 14%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  resize: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
#inputB:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: #1f1f1f;
}
#output {
  width: calc(43% - .86%);
  width: -moz-calc(43% - .86%);
  height: 40vh;
  float: right;
  padding: .43%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Conlang: A Generator</h1>

<textarea id="dic-editor">I would like some chicken abc</textarea>

<div id="translator">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" id="inputB" onclick="trans()">
  <textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```